# PHP: First element of array as a condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have two possible post arrays (held in an array called `$post`). One looks like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["stockist"]=>array(5) {
        [1]=>
        array(5) {
            ["Fcilty_nam"]=>
            string(9) "Test Site"
            ["Shp_num_an"]=>
            string(15) "5 The Test Site"
            ["State"]=>
            string(3) "NSW"
            ["Postcode"]=>
            string(7) "LA7 7BF"
            ["Enabled"]=>
            string(1) "1"
        }
```

The other like this:

```
array(2) {
    ["term"]=>
    string(4)"test"
    ["submit"]=>
    string(6)"search"
    }
```

I'm trying to create a conditional statement that does something dependent on the first array key in the `$post` array. Currently I have this:

```
if ($post[0] == 'term') {
 //do something
}
```

This is not working however. Does anyone know the solution here? Thanks

Comment: Since you don't want to access a key in a subArray, just get the keys of your array into an array, e.g. `$keys = array_keys($yourArray);`

Comment: "This is not working" not helpful. You need to past any error messages in your question, or if there was no error, describe the undesired behavior you saw and how it differs from what you expected.